# AJAX ModalPopup not displaying

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can't seem to get the Modal popup to show. With the code below, the display goes out of focus but no window displays.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AjaxToolkit" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>     
        <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Open ModalPopup" OnClientClick="return ShowModalPopup('modal');" />    
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="modal" BackgroundCssClass="darken" 
                            CancelControlID="btnCancel" PopupControlID="pnl" TargetControlID="btnShow" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" style="width:55%;display:none;">
            <h1>You can now see me!</h1>
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
            pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
            culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Close" />
      </asp:Panel>
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>


    </div> 
    </form>            
</body>
</html>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowModalPop(PopupExtenderID) {
        var ModalPopWindowShow = $find(PopupExtenderID);

        if (ModalPopWindowShow) {
            ModalPopWindowShow.show();
        }

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _grid.DataSource = BuildList();
            _grid.DataBind();
        }

        private List<EntityPerson> BuildList()
        {
            ...
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            btnShow.Click +=new EventHandler(btnShow_Click);
        }

        protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btnShow = sender as Button;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnShow, btnShow.GetType(), "Popup", "return ShowModalPopup('modal');", true);
        }
```

All your help is appreciated.
If there is another way to show a pop up window with AJAX, I would appreciate guidance on that as well. 
I just need to be able to display cell content in a modal window when a user clicks on a cell in a grid.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
```

with

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ajaxSM" runat="server" />
```

and I got the popup to show.